# Does this identity that applies to the metric tensor also apply to the stress-energy tensor?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Okay so if the $g_{00}$ component of the metric is $-c^2$ and $g_{11}=g_{22}=g_{33}$ and all the other other components are zero, the question is simple, would similar identities apply to the stress-energy tensor?

Comment: No........they don't

Comment: Are you asking if $T_{\mu\nu} \propto g_{\mu\nu}$?

Comment: No, not necessarily, I'm just asking if we can know anything about the stress-energy tensor if the metric is a diagonal matrix and the spatial components are all equal to each other.

Comment: I would be interested to see a counter example or a simple proof that a counter example must exist. I think the downvoters should either provide such or withdraw their downvotes.

Comment: Stress-energy tensor of what? Matter? Gravity?

Answer (score 1):

Providing a particular metric tensor, is it possible to know the symmetries of the stress-energy tensor? If it is your question then the answer is following:
For a perfect fluid the stress-energy tensor is $T^{ik}=(p+\rho c^2)u^iu^k-pg^{ik}$. So you need to know the pressure $p$ and the energy-density $\rho$ of the fluid and the time-like velocities $u^i$ (and the metric you already know) to determine the stress-energy tensor. If you know them then you can know about the stress-energy tensor. The metric tensor does not completely determine the stress-energy tensor.
Now you can see that if $g^{ii}$s are equal for $i=1,2,3$ then it is not necessary that $u^i$s will be equal. Therefore, it is not necessary that same identity will also apply for stress-energy tensor. It may be a special case where $u^i$s will be equal and then that identity will be applied for stress-energy tensor also.
For an example, in the co-moving frame of that fluid $u^k=(1,0,0,0)$ for $k=1,2,3$ the $u^i$s are same. Therefore, in this frame, $T^{00}=\rho c^2$ , $T^{11}=T^{22}=T^{33}=-pg^{ii}$ for $i=1,2,3$.